# TFS Sharepoint App - I want a document library column to accept multiple values and... group by?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying and organizing Official Versions of my solutions and projects within Sharepoint Libraries, and I stumbled across this problem:

There are certain published packages which contain more than one project. I'm currently grouping by a "Project" column I created, but some packages seem to belong in more than one area.

[image]

As to say, I want to Split "2011/01 Branch" into 4 website projects. But some packages include more than one website, so I want to see the same file inside every "group".

For instance, I could have a column named Projects with multiple values, so "file_cabbage" would have "Project A", "Project B" and "Project C" as Projects.

So I would have:

Project A:

- file_cabbage

Project B:

- file_cabbage
- file_carrot

Project C:

- file_cabbage
- file_potato

Project D:

- file_carrot
- file_potato

How to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the simple CAML GroupBy doesn't seem to work with choice fields that allow multiple values. The modify list view page only offers you the option to group by a choice field if it is single-valued.

In SharePoint 2010 these views use the XsltListViewWebPart, which gives you sufficient flexibility to produce a list structured in this way provided you are prepared to modify the default XSLT. The downside is that XSLT can be challenging if you are not familiar with it.